# 「と言っても」 vs 「とは言え」

Tags: word-choice, nuances

Hi all is it true that [と言っても](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=toittemo) and [とは言え](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=tohaie) are the same thing except that [と言っても](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=toittemo) is for spoken clauses whereas [とは言え](http://jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=tohaie) is for written clauses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [A Dictionary of Advanced Japanese Grammar](http://bookclub.japantimes.co.jp/en/title/A%20Dictionary%20of%20Advanced%20Japanese%20Grammar), と（は）言っても and とは言え are synonymous and interchangeable without changing the meaning of the sentence. とは言え is used primarily in writing, while と（は）言っても is used in both written and spoken Japanese.

Comment: btw what is the reason that there is an optional は after the と particle?

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry, but I'm honestly not sure of the reason.

Comment: Certain negations are further emphasized with the inclusion of は. Consider "まちがっていない" vs "まちがってはいない". The meaning is the same but usually by putting は, speaker wants to show contrast with another thing.