# いかに～かどうか structure in this sentence

Tags: parsing

> 就職先を失敗して学んだことは、どんな仕事にしろ結局はいかに相手の立場になって物事を考えられるかどうかだと思った。

Speaker talking about a prior job that the speaker quit due to insane hours/low pay

I think that "I learned from failing at my (old) workplace that, whatever job it is, in the end however much i become (?) my partner's standpoint, shuold i consider everything(?)".

I can't quite make sense of what the speaker is trying to say here.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 就職先を失敗して学んだことは、
>   What I learned after failing in choosing a workplace is (that)...
>
> どんな仕事にしろ
>   whatever job it is,
>
> 結局は ～ だと思った
>   I thought it boils down to ～ / after all, it's a matter of ～
>
> いかに相手の立場になって物事を考えられるかどうか
>   how well I can think things from other people's standpoint

The last one is a simple embedded question rather than "no matter how". 立場になる is "to place oneself in a (certain) position", and ～の立場になって is "from ～'s standpoint." 相手 in this context refers to anyone you talk or do business with.

Comment: i think i've only seen いかに～か、instead of 　いかに～かどうか　till now, the latter is much less intuitive. What is the difference?

Comment: @charu Ah, you're right, いかに ("how") doesn't go well with どうか ("whether"), so it's a bit poor-written sentence. It should've been either いかに考えられるか or 考えられるかどうか (without いかに).

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but I'm a bit confused on the use of しろ in どんな仕事にしろ. Is it just the imperative of にする？ Why imperative though? Would something like どんな仕事でも/しても be equivalent?

Comment: @Tommy https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6471/5010 You can also say どんな仕事であれ, どんな仕事でも, どんな仕事であっても, どんな仕事だろうと.